# Call to undefined method can't create createDeleteForm

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I need to create a deleteForm in my view so I do this:

```
/**
 * Show created bank account
 *
 * @Route("/{account_id}", name="wba_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function showAction($account_id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('BankBundle:Account')->find($account_id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Account entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($account_id);
        return array('entity' => $entity, 'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView());
}
```

But I get this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method
>   BankBundle\Controller\WController::createDeleteForm() in
>   /var/www/html/src/BankBundle/Controller/WController.php line 66

What is wrong in this method? I need to use something to create the form?

**Solution**
I found the solution since `createDeleteForm()` isn't Symfony2 method and was my mistake taking it from another code I have so I create the function in this way:

```
private function createDeleteForm($account_id) {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(array('account_id' => $id))->add('account_id', 'hidden')->getForm();
}
```

And voila problem dissapear!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a form like this:

```
$this->createForm(new CreateDeleteType());
```

Of course you also need to create this form:

```
class CreateDeleteType extends AbstractType {
```

Other than that your error message is quite clear. The `method` you are calling (`createDeleteForm`) does not exist. Be aware that `$this` refers to your current **controller context** not the *form context*. Read more about [forms in the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html).